# how to display and then change array of images by set number of click of a button

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, image

I'm working on Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

So far I have connected a button with a label. The label is set at 0 and by clicking it, it will change the number by 1.

Now what I'm trying to do is I want to set an array of images to be displayed after clicking it.

So image 1 shown at 0 then image 2 shown once the button is clicked 1-10 times,

then image 3 shown after button is clicked 20-30 times,

then image 4 is shown after 30-40 clicks/taps of the button.

Also the other images are hidden time the respected number of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pseudo code for array of JPEGs:

```
var arrayOfPictures: [UIImage] = []

arrayOfPictures.append(UIImage(named:"Image1.jpg")!)
arrayOfPictures.append(UIImage(named:"Image2.jpg")!)
arrayOfPictures.append(UIImage(named:"Image3.jpg")!)
```

Here's a pseudo code for button's method:

```
var counter: Int = 0

@IBAction func showPicture(sender: AnyObject?) {

    counter += 1

    if counter == 0 {
        arrayOfPictures[0]
    }
    else if counter >= 1 && counter <= 10 {
        arrayOfPictures[1]
    }
    else if counter >= 11 && counter <= 20 {
        arrayOfPictures[2]
    }
    else if ....................
    ............................
}
```